# Multiple entries per day, converted to day to day and average of value per day

Tags: sql

In SQL, 3 tables joined together, retreving 3 values: `value`, `time`, `value_name`. Value is the one I want averaged by day, `time` is in datetime format on about 10 mins - this one I want it to be converted in day to day, resulting in one row for every day - and my value_name witch cand be any selected value.

Here is my syntax:

```
select time.entry_time, value_type.value_name, 
       avg(value.value) AVG_VALUE
FROM Value
inner join time on value.time_id = time.id
inner join value_type on value.type_id = value_type.id
WHERE value_type.value_name = 'CUSTOM'
GROUP BY DATEPART(DAY, time.entry_time)
```

Here I get an error:

> Column `time.entry_time` is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the `GROUP BY` clause.

Can you please help me with this syntax?

Comment: Could you post example input data & expected output data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two problems:

1. You select `time.entry_time`, but are grouping on `DATEPART(DAY, time.entry_time)`. Which entry time do you want? Did you mean to select `DATEPART(DAY, time.entry_time)` instead?
2. You are not grouping by `value_type.value_name`. You will need to add this to the `GROUP BY` clause. (Yes, even though there will only be one value 'CUSTOM').

Try:

```
select DATEPART(DAY, time.entry_time), value_type.value_name, 
       avg(value.value) AVG_VALUE
FROM Value
inner join time on value.time_id = time.id
inner join value_type on value.type_id = value_type.id
WHERE value_type.value_name = 'CUSTOM'
GROUP BY DATEPART(DAY, time.entry_time), value_type.value_name
```